# Create an "itinerary" agentset of patches

Tags: netlogo

I'm building a model where turtles "search" a subset of patches for a resource according to different search criteria.

I'm trying to build reports that return a sorted list or agentset of patches that a turtle can then use as an itinerary for it's search.

For some reason I'm having trouble storing the itinerary in a turtle owned variable.

an example reporter is:

```
to-report availability

    let sorted-patches sort-on [ ( (space - occupants) / space ) ] patches with [space > 0]

    report sorted-patches

end
```

when I do `show availability` in the console, it prints out what I expect, an ordered list of patches.

But if I do

```
let test-variable availability
show test-variable
```

it returns

```
ERROR: Nothing named TEST-VARIABLE has been defined.
```

is this a problem of scope somehow, can I not use `let` as an observer?

Is it a problem of type? Can I not store an agentset as a named turtle-owned variable?

Is there a way to do the same thing with a list instead of an agent set?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried `let test 3` and `show test` in the console and got the same error so looks like that's the likely problem, what is the workaround?

Comment: I added `test-variable` to `globals` and used `set` and it worked so I'll add that as the answer tomorrow unless there's a better work around or a way to create a variable as an observer using `let` at the console posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it's a scoping problem. But the problem is not that you are trying to use `let` with an observer, it's the scope of `let`. NetLogo is not really interactive in the sense you are trying to do - the variable created by `let` is thrown away at the end of the line.

If you type `let test 3`, hit enter, then type `show test`, you will get the same error. However if you type `let test 3 show test`, then it will return 3.

Why are you needing this from the console? If it's for testing, then you can look at it the way you have already found - simply by `show availability`. If you are using it for turtles while the model is running, then it is not interactive and there's no problem.

Comment: yeah I'm used to trying stuff I'm not sure about in the terminal with R or python before adding it to a file. thanks